# Implies sign in math

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I get myself confused sometimes when to use `=>` or `=`

```
= x + y = x + 5 = x = -5
```

or

```
=> x + y => x + 5 => x = -5
```

Comment: See also "Stream-of-consciousness equalities and implications" section of Common Errors in College Math: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/commerrs/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither of those are right.  It should be:
$$x + y = x + 5 \implies x = -5.$$
(Though I have to say, I'm not exactly sure how $x = -5$ directly follows from $x + y = x + 5$ to begin with.)

---

Let's first distinguish between *expressions* and *equations*.  Expressions are things like $x + 2$ or $37$ or $x^2 - 2x$.  On the other hand, an equation is an equality between two expressions, such as $x + 2 = 3$ or $x = 1$ or $8 + 9 = 17$ and so on.  So, an equality says that two expressions are the same, and we use the equals sign $=$.

Note that an equality is making a logical claim (true or false), whereas an expression is not.  For example, $6 = 6$ is a true equality, whereas $1 = 2$ is a false equality, whereas $17$ is just an expression (not true or false).

Now, the implies sign $\implies$ is used to show that one equation can be logically deduced from another.  So, the implication
$$x + 2 = 3 \implies x = 1.$$
means that from the *equation* $x + 2 = 3$, we can conclude that $x = 1$.

Note that it does *not* make sense to use the implication arrow between *expressions*.  For example $x + y \implies x = -5$ does not make any sense, because the $x + y$ is an expression.  After all, what is the truth value of $x+ y$ anyway?  There isn't one.

Answer (score 9):

The equal sign $"="$ should be used when you have two quantities which are equal.  For example:

$$x^2 + 3x - 4 = (x+4)(x-1).$$

The $"\Rightarrow"$ should be used when relating two statements.  For example:

$$ \text{Today is Tuesday} \Rightarrow \text{Tomorrow is Wednesday}.$$

It is okay to mix them, say for instance you are solving an equation like the following:

$$ 3x + 4 = 10 \Rightarrow 3x = 6 \Rightarrow x = 2.$$

The quantities $3x + 4$ and $10$ are equal.  However, the statement $3x + 4 = 10$ *implies* that $3x = 6$.

Comment: Could we use the equivalence sign also? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score -1):

I think that equal sign is used for showing equality between first and second step but implies that is used for getting into the next step.